# Mouseover on document for find a classes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a code like this, with 2 different divs:

```js
function mouseoverCheck(text) {
  $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    $('#tooltip').show().html(text)
    $('#tooltip').css({
      left: e.pageX,
      top: e.pageY
    }).show();
  });
}

function hover() {
  $(document).on('mouseover', function(event) {

    var $target = $(event.target);
    if ($target.closest(".container1").length) {
      mouseoverCheck('Container1 found!')
      event.stopPropagation();
    } else {
      mouseoverCheck('None')
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tooltip" style="position:absolute; display: none; background: yellow;"></div>

<div class="container1">
  <div class='container2' style="height:200px; width: 100%; border: 3px solid red">
    <div class="container3" style="height:100px; width: 100%">
      <h1 style="font-size: 40px; text-align:center">CONTAINER HOVER</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container4">
  <div class='container5' style="height:200px; width: 100%; border: 3px solid red">
    <h1 style="font-size: 40px; text-align:center">NONE</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to show mi tooltip with text if i pass the mouse over my div , but when i pass over my .container1, it doesn't works good, because it show me 'Container1 found!', alternate by 'None'.

Have you got any other solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code .. Is this what you want??

```js
$('.tooltip_show').on('mousemove' , function(e) {
    $('#tooltip').html($(this).find('h1').text());
    $('#tooltip').css({
      left: e.pageX,
      top: e.pageY
    }).show();
});
$('div :not(.tooltip_show)').on('mouseover' , function(e) {
    $('#tooltip').hide().html('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tooltip" style="position:absolute; display: none; background: yellow;"></div>

<div class="tooltip_show container1">
  <div class='container2' style="height:200px; width: 100%; border: 3px solid red">
    <div class="container3" style="height:100px; width: 100%">
      <h1 style="font-size: 40px; text-align:center">CONTAINER HOVER</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container4">
  <div class='container5' style="height:200px; width: 100%; border: 3px solid red">
    <h1 style="font-size: 40px; text-align:center">NONE</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Add `tooltip_show` class to the container you want to show tooltip